# Disparity Map using sgbm

Tags: c++, opencv

I have captured 2 images containing 2 doors (1 opened, 1 closed) using a stereo camera. The 2 images have been rectified and undistorted. I have tried using the sgbm method in generating the disparity map. Below are the parameters that I have used for the sgbm.

```
numberOfDisparities = 48;
SAD windowsize = 9;

sgbm->setPreFilterCap(63);
sgbm->setBlockSize(9);
sgbm->setP1(8*cn*sgbmWinSize*sgbmWinSize);  //cn=3,sgbmWinSize=9    
sgbm->setP2(32*cn*sgbmWinSize*sgbmWinSize); 
sgbm->setMinDisparity(0);
sgbm->setNumDisparities(48); 
sgbm->setUniquenessRatio(1);
sgbm->setSpeckleWindowSize(100);
sgbm->setSpeckleRange(20);
sgbm->setDisp12MaxDiff(1);
sgbm->compute(img1, img2, disp);

disp.convertTo(disp8, CV_8UC1, 255/(numberOfDisparities*16.));
imshow("disparity8", disp8);
```

The 2 images and the disparity map can be found in this link below.
!(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qbhh6.png)

What parameters do I need to adjust to further improve on the disparity map?

Furthermore, I would like to generate a depth map using the disparity map but not sure how to go about doing it.
Finally, I would like to detect the opened door through the use of the depth map. Anyone has any suggestion or approach on this?

Answer (score 0):

- You can adjust blocksize(odd only), numdisparity ( %16 = 0), uniqueness ratio up to 100.
- You can play with other configuration as well.
- In addition you can use xfilter from opencv-contrib to improve the disparity map from sgbm. What it does is it apply a threshold to your disparity map, use that threshold as an input mask to smooth out your disparity map.